# GTKmm: Open window from another

Tags: gtk, glib, gnome, gtkmm

I want to show a new window, when a button is clicked:

```
void PackBox3::on_button_clicked()
{
    NewCard newcard;
    newcard.show();
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens (I know for sure the method is called), no error message is displayed. My second window looks like this:

```
class NewCard : public Gtk::Window
{
    public:
        NewCard();
        virtual ~NewCard();
   ...
```

How can I make the window show itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
void PackBox3::on_button_clicked()
{
    NewCard newcard;
    newcard.show();

} // newcard destroyed at end of scope here.
```

won't work because the window `newcard` is destroyed at the end of the function's scope. I would suggest making `newcard` a member of `PackBox3` so that is stays alive after the function ends.